# Circular dependencies in ES6 modules and object creation

Tags: javascript, jspm, ecmascript-6

I'm using JSPM with Babel (still v5) to write ES6 code, and also run the code with Karma. I have a strange situation that I can't figure out with circular dependencies in two modules.

On its own it works fine, but it starts to break when I instantiate an object in one of the modules. I don't necessarily use the object, just create an instance.

Example, simplified:

```
// first.js
import second from './second';

export function functionInFirstModule(params) {
}
```

and

```
// second.js
import {functionInFirstModule} from './first';

export default functionInFirstModule({param});
```

Now in `first.js` when I do (anywhere) `let someObject = new Map();` and don't even use it, I get `ERROR: 'Potentially unhandled rejection [3] TypeError: functionInFirstModule is not a function`. Doing `let someObject = {};` works, but `let someObject = Object.create();` does not, and gives me the same error.

Is this something I'm misunderstanding about circular dependencies in module loading or just a bug in JSPM?

Comment: `Potentially unhandled rejection` is an odd error. Are you using a promise somewhere?

Comment: I presume it has something to do with System.js loading. I get similar errors when I try to load a module with a wrong path (the module doesn't exist).